# Carrregar table da view com objeto JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, mvc, razor

Tenho o seguinte código no meu `controller`:

```
public JsonResult List(string nome){

    IList<ClienteDto> clientes = string.IsNullOrEmpty(nome)
        ? _repositoryCliente.Get()
    : _repositoryCliente.GetByName(nome);

    var model = Mapper.Map<IList<ClienteDto>, IList<ClienteViewModel>>(clientes);
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

e esse é o meu JS:

```
function Search(name) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Cliente/List/?nome=" + name,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (clientes) {
            $("#tableClientes").empty();
            url: "/Cliente/Lister/model=" + clientes;
        },
    });
}
```

e aqui o código da view:

```
<table class="table" id="tableClientes">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClienteId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataNascimento)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Telefone)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Situacao)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tbody id="tbody">
        <tr id="tr_@item.ClienteId">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClienteId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.DataNascimento.ToShortDateString()
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Telefone)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Situacao)
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Cliente", new { id = @item.ClienteId })">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" />
                </a>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" onclick="ModalRemove(@item.ClienteId);" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    }
</table>
```

tudo funciona perfeitamente, a pesquisa é feita e retorna um objeto JSON com os dados pesquisados, porém não sei como atualizar a minha `table` com esses dados.
Como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Consegui passar o objeto atualizado do Json, para a controller, porém qdo retorno para view com a model atualizada, a tabela não atualiza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, voce tem duas opcoes, ou popula pelo servidor (no lugar do JsonResult voce retorna uma Action Result e manda os dados para a view). Ou o que mais indico é criar a tabela via jquery, na função success, voce faz o loop em cima das informações recebidas, no caso `clientes`. Na forma mais simples possivel, Ficaria assim:

```
...
 success: function (clientes) {
            $("#tableClientes tbody").empty();
            var tbody = "<tbody>";
            tr = "";
            for (var index in clientes) {
              tr += "<td>" + clientes[index].ClienteId + "</td>";
              tr += "<td>" + clientes[index].Nome + "</td>";

            }
            $('#tableClientes tbody').append(tbody + tr);
        },
...
```